# Several Questions about Alert Me in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, alert

I am working in a List. I see the Alert Me option is offered under the Items AND the List.

If I select the Alert Me option within the Items menu does that create an Alert Me for the Items AND the List?

Or is the Alert Me a separate function for the only an Item and List?

[image]

In addition, why doesn't the Alert Me show up in the My Alert on this Site section after I have selected it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Being alerted on a single item (a single document or a single item in a list) is different than being alerted whenever an item changes in a whole list.

You can decide to be alerted on a single item or the whole list. Alert me on one single item is also possible from the ... (dots - single item menu) or at least it used to in previous versions, then they added the "follow" thing.

For the second question, to be able to see all alerts on you and others you should go to site settings - User alerts

In my case I can see all my alerts in the My alerts on this site.

Answer (score 0):

If I select the Alert Me option within the Items menu does that create an Alert Me for the Items AND the List?  Or is the Alert Me a separate function for the only an Item and List?

- No it's created only for this Item, where the alert title will be created with title of the item title

[image]

Why doesn't the Alert Me show up in the My Alert on this Site section after I have selected it?

- It's shown at manage my alert

[image]

For more details check [Manage Alerts in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-alerts-99dfb19c-9a90-4a8c-aba1-aa8c8afb0de2)

Comment: Thanks. I still don't see the alert me items I have created after I go back to Home/Page/Alert Me/ Manage My Alerts/... it must be due to the permissions I have for the SharePoint site.

Comment: are you tried to create an alert and can't see it in manage my alert ?